# Get R to display and print larger than or equal to sign, smaller than or equal to sign, and superscript using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode, special-characters

Ive got the estimates and corresponding 95% confidence intervals from a regression model, which I am trying to plot.

The data looks as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- structure(list(term = structure(c(1L, 7L, 18L, 19L, 20L), .Label = c("Age (years)", 
"Sex (male)", "Never smoker (reference)", "Current smoker", "Former smoker", 
"Obesity", "BMI (kg/m^2)", "Diabetes", "Glucose (mmol/L)", "Glucose lowering medication use", 
"Hypertension", "Systolic blood pressure (mmHg)", "Diastolic blood pressure (mmHg)", 
"Antihypertensive medication use", "Hypercholesterolemia", "LDL cholesterol (mmol/L)", 
"Lipid lowering medication use", ">90 (reference)", "60-89", 
"<60"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), estimate = c(0.4, 0.9, 
1, 1.5, 1.9), conf_low = c(0.2, 1.4, 0.95, 1, 1.7), conf_high = c(0.6, 
0.6, 1.05, 2, 2.1)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

mydata
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  term            estimate conf_low conf_high
  <ord>              <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Age (years)          0.4     0.2       0.6 
2 BMI (kg/m^2)         0.9     1.4       0.6 
3 >90 (reference)      1       0.95      1.05
4 60-89                1.5     1         2   
5 <60                  1.9     1.7       2.1
```

I have plotted these numbers as follows:

```
ggplot(data=mydata,
  aes(x=estimate, y=fct_rev(term))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=conf_low, xmax=conf_high, height=0.15)) +
  annotation_custom(grob=grid::textGrob(label="Chronic kidney disease", 
                                        gp=grid::gpar(fontface="bold", fontsize=11), 
                                        hjust=1.0), 
                    xmin=-Inf, xmax=-Inf, ymin=3.2, ymax=3.2) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") + 
  #scale_x_continuous(expand=expansion(mult=c(.05, .3))) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(margin=margin(t=0, r=2.2, b=0, l=40, "pt"))) +
  scale_y_discrete(name="")
```

[image]

I'd like to achieve the following things which I can't get to work:

1. In the label of BMI on the Y axis, the ^2 is supposed to be superscript.  I've tried `expression()` but that doesn't seem to work.
2. In the labeling of the Chronic Kidney Disease variable on the y axis, the >90 is supposed to be a 'greater than or equal to' sign, and the <60 an 'smaller than or equal to'. Here I've tried expression and unicodes, but both don't seem to work.

**Edit**
Added session info as this might be useful:

```
library(utils)
sessionInfo(package=NULL)

R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.7     purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.1.0     tidyr_1.1.4     tibble_3.1.6   
[8] ggplot2_3.3.5   tidyverse_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.6.4     compiler_4.1.2   dbplyr_2.1.1     tools_4.1.2     
 [7] digest_0.6.28    jsonlite_1.7.2   lubridate_1.8.0  lifecycle_1.0.1  gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3 
[13] rlang_0.4.12     reprex_2.0.1     cli_3.1.0        rstudioapi_0.13  DBI_1.1.1        haven_2.4.3     
[19] xml2_1.3.2       withr_2.4.2      httr_1.4.2       fs_1.5.0         generics_0.1.1   vctrs_0.3.8     
[25] hms_1.1.1        grid_4.1.2       tidyselect_1.1.1 glue_1.5.0       R6_2.5.1         fansi_0.5.0     
[31] readxl_1.3.1     farver_2.1.0     tzdb_0.2.0       modelr_0.1.8     magrittr_2.0.1   backports_1.3.0 
[37] scales_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.2   rvest_1.0.2      assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_2.0-2 labeling_0.4.2  
[43] utf8_1.2.2       stringi_1.7.5    munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.7.10     crayon_1.4.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you add the unicode?

```
"BMI (kg/m\u00b2)"
"\u2265 90 (reference)" or "\u226590 (reference)"
"\u2264 60" or "\u226460"
```

This seem to work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Merijn. This works now. I tried this last week before updating R and then it did not work. Problem solved!

Comment: As a follow-up question; I left alligned the Y axis lables with `axis.text.y=element_text(hjust=0)`. Is there a way to make a particular label have an indent?

Comment: for center, `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0.5))` and for left, `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0))`

Comment: thanks got it working with a vectorized call to hjust